# String#[] Differences between Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to upgrade an old rails 2.x/ruby 1.8.7 application but I'm
running into an issue. I have the string `\200\001\002\004\b\020` and in my code
I have something that looks like:

```
"\200\001\002\004\b\020"[0]
```

In 1.8.7 this returns the Fixnum `128`. In ruby 1.9.3 (and newer) however this
returns the String `\x80`.

My question is two part: First, what's happening here, and secondly how can I
get a similar behavior to what's being returned in 1.8.7 in newer versions of
ruby?

#### Update #1

As some have suggested I tried `"\200\001\002\004\b\020".bytes[0]` but this however doesn't work (it does work in `2.3.1` though) as it errors with:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Enumerator: "\x80\u0001\u0002\u0004\b\u0010":bytes>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the old behavior, use `String#getbyte`, as in:

> "\200\001\002\004\b\020".getbyte(0)

Comment: This doesn't work in `1.9.3`. It does however work in newer versions (verified on `2.3.1`).

Answer (score 2):

[1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) gives a char code.
[1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) returns a substring.

To obtain the old behaviour, use `"\200\001\002\004\b\020".bytes.to_a[0]`

Comment: This doesn't work in `1.9.3`. It does however work in newer versions (verified on `2.3.1`).

Comment: Blegh. I didn't have an 1.9.3 repl handy. Probably have to call to_a to make the bytes enumerator indexable.